# How to add chromecast to a Video SDK Swift

Tags: ios, sdk, integration, chromecast, ios14

I am creating a Playback SDK, using AVFoundation (AVPlayer) in swift.

I am trying to add Chromecast to my playback, but I'm not sure how I can add the bonjour services to my playback SDK.

According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/ios_permissions_changes) I need to add the following to my info.plist:

```
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
  <string>_googlecast._tcp</string>
  <string>_ABCD1234._googlecast._tcp</string>
</array>
```

I can add the following to my plist, but obviously that won't work `_ABCD1234` (which is the receiver app ID), as this will be provided by developers whom will be responsible for integrating my SDK in their app.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something very obvious here, or if there's something I need to do, but I can't figure out how to go about doing this?

I have thought about the following solutions (which won't work):

1. Injecting the above entry into my plist when a developer provides this to my SDK
2. leaving it out

I appreciate any help anyone can give me with this, as it has wrecked my brain.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to provide integration documentation that explains to developers the changes they need to make to their info.plist to use chrome cast support in your sdk

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the reply. I see what you mean, so they only need to have it in their plist, and I can handle other aspects of chromecast? Again, thanks a lot and I will update the question with the documentation and code for chromecast integration, so that other can use them if they're in the same situation.